# How to Remove "Microsoft Power BI" footer from the report while publishing to web

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

Please let us know how to remove "Microsoft Power BI" footer from the report while publishing to web.

Please find the below snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Power BI Publish To Web is a free capability, and comes with several limitations.  If you want full control over the resulting web page, use Power BI Embedding with a custom web site.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, Power bi gives back an Iframe, and you have no control over it. If you want to have this control use power bi embedded instead.

Answer (score 1):

Link Powerbi + &navContentPaneEnabled=false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).